# Conditional Probability — Hint needed.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

I have the following problem:

when buying a new device, the device does not work in 20% of the cases, does work for one year in 30% of the cases, and works for 5 years in the remaining 50% of the cases. 
what is the probability that my newly bought device works for 5 years, given it works fine right now.

I tried to set up the following probabilites

N = 'new'

W_x = 'Working for x years', where x can be 0,1 or 5

therefore I have:

$$P(W_0|N) = 0.2; P(W_1|N) = 0.3; P(W_5|N) = 0.5 $$

But I don't know how to proceed further. Can you give me a hint?

I thought of Bayes formula being:
$$ P(A|B) = \frac{P(A and B)}{P(B)}$$
however when I try to figure out
$$ P(W_5|not W_0)= \frac{P(W_5 and not W_0}{P(notW_0)} = \frac{0.5*0.8}{0.8}$$ which does not seem to be correct...

Comment: First, that's not Bayes' Formula, but no big deal. Second, note that $W_5$ and $(\text{not } W_0)$ are NOT independent events. You can't just multiply their individual probabilities.

Comment: ah, my bad. I changed it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed go for finding $$P(W_5\mid W_0^{\complement})=P(W_5\cap W_0^{\complement})/P(W_0^{\complement})=P(W_5)/(1-P(W_0))$$

Observe that $W_5\cap W_0^{\complement}=W_5$.

Comment: ok, so my original thought was correct. why is $$P(W_5 and  W_0^c) the same as P(W_5) only..$$?

Comment: Working for $5$ years is the same as working for $5$ years and (consequently) not for only $0$ years.

Comment: The events $W_5$ and $W_0$ are *mutually exclusive*, i.e. $W_5\cap W_0=\varnothing$ or equivalently $W_5\subseteq W_0^{\complement}$ or equivalently $W_5\cap W_0^{\complement}=W_5$.

Comment: ah. now I get it. thanks.